# Ruby, is this Binary Tree Correct?

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree

So im going through the OdinProject and starting on the "BinaryTree" portion. I've written a Binary Tree but only in C++ using pointers. So without pointers it's a little more confusing to me at how the nodes connect:

```
class Node

  attr_accessor :value, :parent, :left, :right
  @@nodes = 0

  def self.nodes
    @@nodes
  end

  def initialize(value, parent=nil)
    @value = value
    @parent = parent
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
    @@nodes += 1
  end

end


class BinaryTree

  def initialize
    @root = nil
  end

  def build_tree(arr)
    arr.each {|el| add_child(el,@root)}
    @root
  end

  def add_child(value,node)
    if @root.nil?
      @root = Node.new(value)
    else
      if value < node.value
        node.left.nil? ? node.left = Node.new(value,node) : add_child(value,node.left)
      elsif value > node.value
        node.right.nil? ? node.right = Node.new(value,node) : add_child(value,node.right)
      end
    end
    return node
  end

end
```

I've done some basic print functions, and it SEEMS to be working correctly, but I was wondering if this looks correct to others that understand ruby better. (Sidenote: I realize this does not handle duplicate numbers). Am I missing something with the "building" portion of the tree.

The reason im concerned is a see a lot of different "build" implementations. One that starts at the midpoint for instance, or is this just for "Sorted" arrays?

Comment: [Binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Methods_for_storing_binary_trees) is a data structure. But what you were trying to do is building then sorting a binary tree. Which one do you want? If it's the latter, I think  your code is pretty clear and straightforward. But a little error, your `Binary#build_tree` method accepts an array, if this array contains many node objects, then the code should be `arr.each {|el| add_child(el.value,@root)}`, cause you can't compare an object with an integer.

Comment: @Caven Im wanting to Build a binary tree, the sorting is less important to me (Well technically the build should be sorting them correctly as a binary tree is built). Also the "input" is supposed to just simply be an array of numbers never node objects.

Comment: People who start with a sorted array and pick the midpoint as the first root might want to generate a balanced binary tree.

Comment: Thats probably what im thinking of. Typically BST's are expected unsorted arrays right?

Comment: It depends on your main purpose.  If you just wanna construct a binary tree data structure, then you needn't to consider too much about other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to the ruby world! Beware you might really like it and never come back to another language :)

Here are some comments I can give you:

### Testing

First thing when you wonder if your code is correct is to test it with different inputs. You can do it by hand, in the console, or you can write tests that will follow you during the development.

#### By printing

A quick way of testing what you do is to define the `to_s` method on your `Node` class. For instance, this will allow to check your tree is ordered:

```
class Node
  …
  def to_s
     "#{left} #{value} #{right}".strip
  end
end
```

`to_s` is the default ruby method used when converting an object to a string. You can for instance do:

```
#> puts BinaryTree.new.build_tree([5, 9, 1, 6])
1 5 6 9
```

#### By testing

For your peace of mind, you can describe some tests that will allow you to write code, and modify it, and check it is still working. I would suggest minitest for doing it easily.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe BinaryTree do
  before do
    @constructor = BinaryTree.new
  end

  describe 'when given an array' do
    it 'sorts it' do
      @constructor.build_tree([1, 3, 2]).to_s.must_equal '1 2 3'
    end
  end

  describe 'when given an array with duplicates' do
    it 'builds the correct tree' do
      @constructor.build_tree([1, 3, 2, 3]).to_s.must_equal '1 2 3 3'
    end
  end
end
```

You can then run it with `ruby -Ilib:test binary_tree.rb` if `binary_tree.rb` is the file where you put your code.

You will see there, as you mentioned, that the duplicate code doesn’t work.
You can make it work by removing a condition in the `if…elsif` block.

Then you wan work on the code and run the test as often as you like so that you are confident you didn’t break anything.

Each time you have an edge case you are not sure your code handles, just put that in a test.

### Counting the nodes

Your `Node.nodes` method is probably not what you want if it is supposed to count the number of nodes in your binary tree.
It should be in the instance of a `Node`, not in the class itself: if you have several trees, all nodes are taken into account for each tree.

### Ruby things

Some of the things you write could be expressed differently in ruby:

#### Nil is not necessary

`attr_accessor parent` is syntactic sugar for

```
def parent
  @parent
end

def parent=(other)
  @parent = other
end
```

In ruby if your instance variable `@parent` is not declared, it has the value `nil` by default, and calling `node.parent` will return `nil` too.

You don’t need these 2 lines in the initializer:

```
@left = nil
@right = nil
```

#### Return is not necessary

When your last instruction in a method is a return, you don’t need the `return` keyword. That is what I did with the `to_s` method above.

#### Named parameters

I think it is cleaner to have named parameters when they are not obvious.
For instance, calling `Node.new(value, node)` doesn’t really help understanding what are these 2 parameters for. I get that a node should have a value, but what is this second parameter?

You could define:

```
def initialize(value, parent: nil)
  # Same as before
end
```

and call it with `Node.new(value, parent: node)`, or `Node.new(value)`

### OO things

#### Moving methods where they belong

Your `BinaryTree#add_child` method should be on a node. You are adding a child to the node. Move it there, so you don’t need your second parameter:
`add_child(value, node.right)` becomes `node.right.add_child(value)`

```
class Node
  ...
  def add_child(other_value)
    if other_value < value
      left.nil? ? self.left = Node.new(other_value, parent: self) : left.add_child(other_value)
    else
      right.nil? ? self.right = Node.new(other_value, parent: self) : right.add_child(other_value)
    end
  end
end

class BinaryTree
  ...
  def add_child(value)
    if @root.nil?
      @root = Node.new(value)
    else
      @root.add_child(value)
    end
    @root
  end
end
```

While you are there you could also get rid of `build_tree` in the `BinaryTree` class, and move it to the `Node`.

I hope it will help you in your Ruby Journey.

Comment: Thanks! So it sounds like at least my tree building solution was on the right track? these are helpful comments though. Im a bit confused how the `to_s` correct prints the nodes in order however?

Comment: What a lovely answer : )

Comment: Also Im a bit confused at what your saying with defining `@parent` as well.

Comment: About your first comment: your solution was definitely on the right track. Not sure what confuses you about `to_s`; this is what binary trees are about: sorting values, smaller on the left, larger on the right. We print all nodes on the left (by construction only nodes with a value smaller than the root are there), and we finish with the right and larger values. Repeat in sub-trees.

Comment: And about your comment on `@parent`, not sure either what confuses you. My only point is to tell you an empty instance variable like `@parent` exists event the first time you access its value, and is equal to `nil`.